# IDE configuration for Android Platform development

Tags: android, ide, platform

I'm currently working on Android Platform.

I download the source and build it perfectly.

I have now, some trouble to configure Android Studio IDE to work on the code.

The problem is there are no Android Studio project file or something else in the android repo. To me, it's necessary to load properly java file (and native C) correctly in the IDE.

As android use .mk file to compile C/C++ file, it's look like necessary to use Android Studio.

Maybe I'm doing something wrongly... Does anyone have ever had this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> make idegen && development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh

in AOSP root and then you can open it like any other Android Studio project. "Open Project" and that is it.